# how to make fluid Img component smaller than its container element

Tags: gatsby

I read here (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#avoiding-stretched-images-using-the-fluid-type) that I should be able to make a Gatsby  component stay at its max width even when that is smaller than the width of the parent container element. I believe I understand what is going on in the code sample they give in the docs, but when I try to adapt it to my code, the image still stretches to fill the container width.

Their code:

```
// in React component
const NonStretchedImage = props => {
  let normalizedProps = props
  if (props.fluid && props.fluid.presentationWidth) {
    normalizedProps = {
      ...props,
      style: {
        ...(props.style || {}),
        maxWidth: props.fluid.presentationWidth,
        margin: "0 auto", // Used to center the image
      },
    }
  }

  return <Img {...normalizedProps} />
}
```

Note: The GatsbyImageSharpFluid fragment does not include presentationWidth. You will need to add it in your graphql query as is shown in the following snippet:

```
{
  childImageSharp {
    fluid(maxWidth: 500, quality: 100) {
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      presentationWidth
    }
  }
}
```

My code:

```
// in React component
<Img
      fluid={data.myImage.childImageSharp.fluid}
      alt="description"
      fadeIn={true}
      style={{
        ...(props.style || {}),
        maxWidth: props.fluid.presentationWidth,
        margin: "0 auto", // Used to center the image
      }}
    />

// in GraphQL query
myImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "imageName.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 400) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
          presentationWidth
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's just css & not a gatsby specific thing. Have you inspected the result html? Check what's preventing the child image to scale. If you can share a live build link, or re-create the output html & css, it'll be helpful!

Comment: Thanks everyone. When I set maxWidth manually, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, adding `!important` to your css rules can fix issues.
Also check the rendered page HTML output inside `developer console`.
They tend to create a lot of nested html and thus prevent your css to work as intended.